# which is better "destination, source" or "source, destination"?

Tags: api, copy

My question is language transcendent, I've often found prototypes of "copy" functions define parameters in the order: argument1:"destination" then argument2:"source".
It is the case of memcpy for example in C. But it is NOT the case of file copy on bash ! You say, e.g.: "$ cp file file2" where file2 is the new file.
Which makes much more sense to me, we always say "copy that text here please" and not "copy here that text" which is Yoda-esque.

So the true question is: a good API should use what form (order) ? and maybe another subsidiary question: what form is everybody expecting, if there is any ?

Comment: This question has been asked already here. I am trying to find it, though, help me. :)

Comment: I don't find the answer anymore, so I give a short summary: x86 assembly uses "mnemocode destination, source", like "mov ah, 17h", in school we learn that "y = 17 * x", and when speaking we say "y is 17 times x". And in most (natural) languages, the subject comes before the verb. So again, "y is 17 times x". But at the same time, if you move a box, you say, "move this box over there next to the wall". In that case, the source ("what" = subject) is first, and the destination second.

Comment: @shi, note that when using gas (the GNU assembler) it's inverted: `mv $17, %ah`, so I'm not sure that assembly is a good argument.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I expect source to come first, and destination later.

If you can disambiguate in the language, it would be better. For example, in a OO language:

```
source.copyTo(destination);
```

In a language with named parameters:

```
copy(source: s, destination: d);
```

The important thing is to make *clear* what's going on for people *reading* the code. Code is more often read than it's written.

Comment: just wanted to add, in the standard C library, functions like memcpy do destination, source:                               void *memcpy(void *dest, const void * src, size_t n); which translates to destination.copyFrom(source) in OOP

Answer (score 1):

I've always preferred source-destination (I'm pushing from here to here), but it probably also depends on the call.  If it's only 'copy' you're referring to, I think this works.  I'm sure there's there are other *pull* oriented calls that dest-source would apply better to.